# Transfer / Withdrawal of all funds in an RPP

Tags: canada, retirement-plan

An individual has a Registered Pension Plan, and has recently retired.

The plan management company is restricting access to the funds to a specific amount per month, which is insufficient for the individual's needs. The fund has offered a one-time "hardship amount", but is otherwise unwilling to increase the monthly access limit, provide a lump-sum transfer/payment, or allow unlimited access to the pension funds.

In this situation, are there any options available to gain access to the full amount of the RPP, or at least, the ability to withdraw ad-hoc amounts from the balance?

Comment: What does the individual plan to live on once they have spent all their RPP?

Comment: The rules are federal or provincial, so specific to the job and jurisdiction.  Here is a federal example.  https://www.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/Eng/pp-rr/faq/Pages/ulfpp-lrsp.aspx